# Me devuelve undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Buenas, tengo un formulario que a través de AJAX y PHP hago una consulta a mi BD para devolver algunos de los datos, el problema está en que me devuelve undefined cuando intento pintar en consulta un dato del array JSON, he mirado el debug del navegador y en PHP si me hace la consulta bien devolviendome el array correctamente. Dónde puede estar el fallo ? Gracias !!

PD: no hay fallos en las librerías jquery, etc ,etc. Funcionan correctamente.

**form.php (AJAX)**

```
...                   
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label class="col-md-3" for="telf">Nº de teléfono:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <input type="text" name="telf" id="telf" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button id="buscar" name="buscar">Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

...

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $(document).on("click", "#buscar", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var telf = $('#telf').val();

    var url = "buscar.php";
    var dataValue = {'telf': telf};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataValue,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.nombre_cli);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

**buscar.php (SQL)**

```
<?php 

require("conexion.php");

$telf= $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['telf']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT nombre_cli, ... FROM ... WHERE num_telefono = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $telf);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

$json = array();
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json["data"][] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($json);

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te devuelve `undefined` porque estás intentando acceder a un dato que no existe. Estás guardando tus datos en `PHP` dentro de un `Array` con clave `data` por lo que lo que recibirás será un objeto con esta forma:

```
{"data": [...datos que insertas desde la base de datos...]}
```

O cambias tu implementación de `PHP` para que no cree ese índice `data`, o deberías acceder primero a ese parámetro antes de intentar acceder en `JavaScript` a los datos:

```
console.log(data.data<datos a los que quieres acceder>);
```

Por otro lado al llamar a `fetch_assoc` estás creando un `Array` asociativo por lo que la estructura será:

```
{data: [{"nombre_cli" : "contenido de nombre_cli"}, ...]}
```

Consulta [el siguiente snippet](http://ideone.com/IGR1Dk) para que comprendas la estructura que estás creando.

Con esa estructura la manera en `JavaScript` de acceder al primer dato sería:

```
data.data[0].nombre_cli;
```

Lo mejor es que hagas un `console.log` de lo que recibes del servidor:

```
console.log(data);
```

Así verás la estructura que tiene el objeto y podrás acceder a sus datos guiándote por dicha estructura.

Comment: y si quisiese que me mostrase todos los datos de nombre_cli? es decir, que no fuese solo el dato 0 del array, o no sería posible ? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Deberías hacer un `for` en `JavaScript` desde `0` hasta la longitud del `Array` que recibes y acceder a los datos contenidos en `data.data[index del ciclo].nombre_cli;`.

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias por tus respuestas, estaba ya estresado con este tema jaja :D

Comment: Me alegro que no te cause más estrés ;)